# Uploading website to Host

Tags: uploads, hosting, backup

My website is currently on localhost but painfully slow.

I am going to upload it to `000webhost.com` who offer a free hosting service. I am keen to see if this speeds things up.

I was wondering if there is anything I need to do when uploading my website, taking off localhost and moving to `000webhost.com`.

Currently all files are saved in `WAMP` in a folder called `Wordpress`...

Should it be as simple as uploading this file to my new host?

I was also keen to hear if anyone could advise as to the best for products for backing up a wordpress site?

Thank you in advance.

Sorry, I meant to also ask, Is it a bad idea to upload to one host then move to another when I am setting it live as I was planning on going to 1&1 for setting the website live

Comment: Your site URL is going to change, [read here what the codex writes about this](https://codex.wordpress.org/Changing_The_Site_URL).

Answer (score 0):

I use **Search-Replace-DB** from *interconnectit* for years now and had always good results with replacing urls. In case you have Yoast SEO plugin installed you might have to deactivate it when you rewrite the urls, otherwise I never had trouble using that scripts up to now.

https://github.com/interconnectit/Search-Replace-DB

Answer (score 0):

User [WP Duplicator](https://wordpress.org/plugins/duplicator/) plugin (install on your local wordpress...create archive and then upload to root folder and open in browser)

It is de facto solution for upload wordpress website from localhost to remote server....you wont be needing to change URL's in database manually...everything will be done by itself.

Comment: Looks like a decent option, will have a proper look at this when I get back to my computer, thanks :-)

Answer (score 0):

Codex has thorough general instructions on [moving WordPress](https://codex.wordpress.org/Moving_WordPress) and bits that need adjustment under different scenarios. There are many tools/plugins that automate the process/parts to a different degree and fashion. Specific approach is mostly matter of personal taste and technical chops.

Do note that most shared hosting accounts would be vastly inferior in resources to any modern desktop. If your site is slow on your local machine you probably have work to do on that before getting it live in production.

Comment: Thank you for your response. It is not only the site that is slow on my desctop, it is the full wordpress CMS and has been slow since day one. I just assumed that this was due to running on locallhost?

Comment: No, localhost will typically be faster than cheap hosting.

Comment: I know this might be hard to answer. But if my localhost has been slow since day one, is there anything that might cause that? Id imagine plugins etc wouldnt be an issue as it was slow before I added anything

Comment: There are many things that can cause that. Faulty code, misconfigured server stack, overly heavy site configuration, etc.

Comment: Thanks I will need to find a way to diagnose the issue :-s lol

Comment: One last question, sorry. Could the fact I have a Magento folder also on my localhost contribute to the slow running?

Comment: Who knows. This isn’t guessable, you need to figure it own for your specific install.

Answer (score 0):

The best option you have i guess would be to use a great plugin named Duplicator.
Here is a link to the plugin, its free and extremely useful.

Link: https://wordpress.org/plugins/duplicator/

This plugin will pack your wordpress installation into zip file, then you will download this file from localhost and you will upload it to the remote server, this zip file comes also with a .php file that is used to re extract the data, the only thing you need to do is make a new empty database and then upload this zip and .php file to your remote server, then the setup process will guide you.
Hope this was helpful.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Follow These **5 steps** to Get your site up on live server from Localhost

For ex. moving this `http://localhost/wordpress to http://www.example.com`

1 )  **Export your database** from phpmyadmin

2 )  Open your database with any editor and use **find replace function to change URLS** path 
`find http://localhost/wordpress and replace with http://www.example.com`

3 ) **Create database** on your live server , keep in write database **usernam**e and **password** for future use. Now import database

4 ) Now, come to **wp-config.php** and change your **DB_NAME, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD**

5 ) Settings are done , Now **Upload your files** to live server and check your **permanent links** settings, change to original setting which use used on local host.